# I have been trying to write a program to convert decimal to binary , I don't know what is wrong with my code ? i am using codeblocks

Tags: c, bit-shift

this is my code , I think something wrong with the shift operator , I used them in embedded software but I don't know if it is ok to use them on normal code , I have written a code to do the same purpose but with the method of adding (2*10^digit) but it seems a lot easier to use shifts-if possible-, please help :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double find_power(double x);
int main()
{
    double bin=00000000, dec , k ;
    printf("enter decimal number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&dec);
    for(;;)
    {
        k=find_power(dec);
        bin|=(1<<k);
        dec-=pow(2,k);
        if(dec==1)
        {
            bin|=(1<<0);
            break;
        }
        else if(dec==0)
        {
            bin&=(~(1<<0));
            break;
        }

    }

    printf("%d",bin);
    return 0;
}

double find_power(double x)
{
    double i=1,j=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        i*=2;
        if(x>=i)
        {
            j++;
        }
        else if(x<i)
        {
             break;
        }

    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: Bitwise operations requires `int`s instead of `double`s

Comment: What's your input/output/expected output ? also, if you only need to print in binary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: Did this code compiled OK? Seems it has casting problems.

Comment: Codeblocks is an IDE, not a compiler. Are you using gcc?

Answer (score -1):

You are wildly mixing `double` and `int` all over the code. You try to read an `int` into a `double` with scanf, which invokes undefined behavior. And then you try to use `double` variables together with bitwise operators, which most likely doesn't make any sense. You'll want to use an unsigned integer of known size instead.

You should enable/listen to compiler warnings.